# Enforce explicit template filter dependencies with Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

If I've got a template that uses a custom filter:

```
{{ foo|myfilter }}
```

Is there any way to ensure that the filter `myfilter` has been explicitly included by the controller rendering the template?

I ask because I want to make sure that one module's import of a filter doesn't implicitly provide that filter to other modules (which would then break if the first reference is removed).

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs, when you register a filter, it will actually end up as a service with `Filter` suffix.

Therefore in your case, you could inject the `myfilterFilter` service in a controller.

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function ($filter, myfilterFilter) {
   var isSame = ($filter('myfilter') === myfilterFilter);
   console.log(isSame);
});
```